# Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship 'Product_CreatedByUser' was not loaded because the type 'User' is not available

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I have following code first models and I try to initialized database it giving me error mention below. One user can have multiple products so there is one to many relationship between user and product.

```
Schema specified is not valid. Errors: The relationship 'Models.Product_CreatedByUser' was not loaded because the type 'User' is not available.
```

I am using code first approach, can any one help me with this.

User:

```
public class User
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Product:

```
public class Product
    {
    public long ProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public long CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public long ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CreatedBy")]
    public virtual User CreatedByUser { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ModifiedBy")]
    public virtual User ModifiedByUser { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You have 2 one-to-many relationships between `User` and `Product`, which one is supposed to be represented by the `User.Products` navigation property - created or modified?

Comment: @IvanStoev Should be both, as user can add or update products.

Comment: The problem is that unfortunately it *can't* - EF requires separate (or no) navigation property for each relationship. So you either create 2 properties like `User.CreatedProducts` and `User.ModifiedProducts` (and map them properly), or map `User.Products` to one of the FKs using `InverseProperty` attribute or fluent configuration.

Comment: @IvanStoev Thank you so much, your suggestion fixed my issue. I have created separate properties and map them which fixed my problem. You can post that as answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the model, `Product` has 2 many-to-one FK relationships to `User` - 1 through `CreatedBy` and 1 through `ModifiedBy`. However, the `User` class contains a single `Products` collection, while EF requires one or zero corresponding navigation property *for each* relationship. Also, it doesn't know to which of the current FK is supposed to map that collection, so it silently tries to create a 3rd relation :( Since the default mapping doesn't work for such scenarios, you need to use `InverseProperty` or fluent API to specify the mappings correctly.

For instance, the bidirectional mapping can be specified like this:

```
public class User
{
    public long UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("CreatedByUser")]
    public virtual ICollection<Product> CreatedProducts { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("ModifiedByUser")]
    public virtual ICollection<Product> ModifiedProducts { get; set; }
}
```

**Upate:** While the above fixes the mapping issue, it introduces another issue known as *multiple cascade paths*, because by the default EF conventions cascade delete is on for one-to-many relationships. Since you need fluent configuration anyway to turn the cascade delete off for one or both relationships, you'd better remove `ForeignKey` and `InverseProperty` annotations and configure the whole thing fluently:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.CreatedByUser)
    .WithMany(e => e.CreatedProducts)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.CreatedBy)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .HasRequired(e => e.ModifiedByUser)
    .WithMany(e => e.ModifiedProducts)
    .HasForeignKey(e => e.ModifiedBy)
    .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```