# EF6 create one to many relationship when the 'many entity has the 2 fields of same type

Tags: entity-framework-6, migration, one-to-many

I want to create a one to many relationship in the following edge case:
I have a user that can have many notifications.

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{ 
    public List<SentNotification> SentNotifications { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        SentNotifications = new List<SentNotification>();
    }
}
```

Each notification has a sent by user and received by user.

```
public class SentNotification
{
    public User Receiver { get; set; }

    public User Sender { get; set; }
}
```

When I generate the schema I receive the following migration:

```
public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.SentNotifications",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    ReceiverId_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                    SenderId_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                    User_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.ReceiverId_Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.SenderId_Id)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.AspNetUsers", t => t.User_Id)
            .Index(t => t.ReceiverId_Id)
            .Index(t => t.SenderId_Id)
            .Index(t => t.User_Id);

    }
```

QUESTION:
Is there a way when declaring the entities to have EF generate a migration that is aware that Sender is the foreign key for the one to many relationship and this without tempering the generated migration code ?

Comment: 2 `User` properties (FKs) require 2 `List<SentNotification>` collections. e.g. `SentNotifications` and `ReceivedNotifications`. Plus proper mapping. Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44363923/schema-specified-is-not-valid-errors-the-relationship-product-createdbyuser/44365063#44365063

Comment: I am starter in EF, so to clarify I have understood correctly: I should declare:


`public class SentNotification
{
    public User Receiver { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("SentNotifications")]
    public User Sender { get; set; }
}`


The generated migration seems to have the required fields, does EF also know that SentNotifications from User is linked to Sender from SentNotifications ?

Comment: That's what the `InverseProperty` attribute does - links `SentNotification.Sender` to `User.SentNotifications`. But note that if you don't add a second collection and link it to the `Receiver`, you'll not be able to retrieve the notifications received by an user.

Comment: thank you for clearing things, if you want you can copy paste the code and I will accept it as an answer